# Bigcartel bxslider image twitch?

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider, bigcartel

Hey all I'm working on a site for a client but there is this annoying twitch present when the image transitions. The theme is a modified Luna theme (noticed that they now support flexslider am I going down the wrong path?) was just wonder what people thought?

[Link to site](http://goodoldboys.bigcartel.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to your CSS should do the trick:

```
.bx-viewport {
  -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
  -moz-transform: translatez(0);
  -ms-transform: translatez(0);
  -o-transform: translatez(0);
  transform: translatez(0);
}
```